# Multiple Primary Keys in Nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, orm, mapping

How do you assign multiple Primary Keys while Mapping in NHibernate?

```
    Id(x => x.TopicID); <<----Primary Key
        Map(x => x.Topic);   <<---Should Also be a Primary Key
        Map(x => x.Subtitle);
        Map(x => x.Description);
        Map(x => x.ImageURL);

    }
```

Comment: Isn't Topic an object, not an ID?  p.s. you should really mark some accepted answers - you've asked 12 questions, but not accepted any - this is not good for your reputation.

Comment: Do you mean a composite key or — as the word "also" suggests — an alternate key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the CompositeID method:

```
CompositeId()
.KeyProperty(x => x.TopicId, "name")
.KeyReference(x => x.Topic, "anotherName");
```